# Pycharm debugger error

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I am trying to run the pycharm debugger but he not working, for all my files (which he work for them last night)
this is the erorr:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 60124 --file C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py
pydev debugger: process 6168 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 143.595)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I admit it's a bit silly, but make sure that you have the correct Run/Debug configuration selected in the dropdown. You might have accidentally changed it. Then of course none of your breakpoints will work and you might not realize the issue if the other script doesn't have any output.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on the same issue for a while, but reading over these two threads at the developer's site made me find the issue:

- [Pycharm debugger not working](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000014004-Pycharm-debugger-not-working)
- [Debugger not working: code is executed normally](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207609385-Debugger-not-working-code-is-executed-normally)

In my case, it was because the **Breakpoints** setting had become incorrect somehow. To fix it, go to the **Breakpoints** menu by clicking here (or CTRL+SHIFT+F8):

[image]

Then set the settings to something like this. The top option **Enabled** was disabled in my case.

[image]

After this, it worked as usual in my case.

--

Versions:

- Pycharm 2017.1.1 professional
- Python 3.5.1
- Django 1.10

Answer (score 1):

Remove all set breakpoints and then retry debugging. To do this press `<CTRL>+<SHIFT>+<F8>` then select all breakpoints then click the (-) button. This problem can occur across multiple versions.