# Pycharm local debugging will not work

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

For some reason my PyCharm will no longer debug locally. I have a very simple script to prove the point:

```
x = 5 * 5
y = 3
z = x / y
print(z)
```

With breakpoints in it. The breakpoints are not hit, z is not printed, and I get no errors. The output is:

> /Users/username/anaconda/envs/envname/bin/python
>   "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py"
>   --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 50351 --file /Users/username/Documents/Workspace/pleasedebug/debugscript.py
>   pydev debugger: process 752 is connecting
>
> Connected to pydev debugger (build 143.2370)
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

It looks like it's trying to connect for remote debugging, but I can't find any info on how to tell it to just debug the script locally.

Comment: are you sure haven't muted your breakpoints ?

Comment: Yeah, I've turned them on and off multiple times and removed them and re-added them. The print statement should still work either way, but the debug isn't running the script.

Comment: I've updated to the latest PyCharm community edition and I didn't import my settings and I don't see the issue anymore. Something went wrong with my PyCharm 5.0 that I can't seem to resolve and I'd still like to fix it just in case it happens again.

Comment: I've come across this issue with pycharm 2016.3.3 on windows. Program runs fine, but can't debug. The problem shows across all projects. I do have debug headers installed for writing a c++ module, so wondering if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224246/pycharm-debugger-error, check that for more ideas.